# Python beginner taking Python for Everybody course on Coursera - struggling with numbers assignment 5.2

Tags: python, numbers

So the task is to:

"Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below."

I'm still kind of new to Python but I can't seem to achieve this assignment on my own. I kind of want to avoid just copying someone else's code because the teacher of the module Charles Severence, says that's not a good idea. But I'm also getting tired of this assignment that probably does not reflect anything I would normally want to use python for as a programmer.

This is my code at the moment. It seems like no matter what I change there is always a new error:

Please help, suggest solutions and tell me the mistakes I'm making.

EDIT:

I have received comments about the indentation errors and I wanted to clarify that these were typos I caused when copying my code into this forum. Anyway, I have adjusted my code and it no longer has the problem of not accepting 'done' or not continuing the loop after an invalid input. Now, the difficulty I'm having is retrieving the maximum and minimum values with or without a list function. Also, at this point I'm so stuck I wouldn't mind receiving some direct answers with working code.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
number_list = []
while True:
    num = input('Enter a number:')
    if num == 'done' : break
    try:
        num = int(num)
        number_list.append(num)
    except:
        print ('Invalid Input')
    continue
def max(num):
    for largest in number_list[num]:
        if largest < num:
            largest = num
        return largest
def min(num):
    for smallest in number_list[num]:
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
        if smallest > num:
            smallest = num
        return smallest
print ('Maximum is',max(num))
print ('Minimum is',min(num))
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the error message to your question and state the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't heard of lists yet.

The way I would solve it would be to use a list to store all the values and then applying the `max(list)` and `min(list)` built-in functions.

```py
alln = list()
num=""

while num!='done':
    num = input('Enter a number:')
    
    try:
        alln.append(float(num))
    except:
        print('invalid input')
    
print ('Maximum is',max(alln))
print ('Minimum is',min(alln))
```

Like this

Check [this](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-min-and-max/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20max()%20function,holds%20a%20list%20or%20string.) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/) to understand the basics of lists and how to work with those two functions.

---

### Now the problems with your code

**1. You have several indentation errors.**

```py
    for largest_num in [uval]:
        if largest is not None or uval > largest:
        ^here, the 'if' should be inside the 'for' block and it wasn´t. You have this problem twice in your code

while True:
    num = input('Enter a number:')
    uval = float(num)
    if num == str:
    elif num == str('done'):
    ^here, all four need an extra space to be properly indented
```

**2. Because of this**

```py
    num = input('Enter a number:')
    uval = float(num)
```

**When you write "done", you get another error. Try doing this instead:**

```py
while True:
    if num == 'done':
        break
    #check if it's not a number
    else:
        num = float(num)
        #store the value as a float
```

That way you can avoid converting a `string` to a `float`, which is why you are getting the error

---

Other problems I found

1. Both prints have indentation errors. But assuming that's just a typo, the indentation itself will make the loop print every single time it runs because it's inside the 'for' block.
2. `str('done')` this doesn't work because `str()` will transform the argument to a string. Remember that `'done'` is already considered a string by python, so you can just write `num == 'done'`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I fixed the indentation errors (which were just caused by my sloppy copying and pasting into the forum). Now the main problem is that the maximum value keeps getting printed as 'done' and when I added the list function (which hasn't been taught on my course yet) it did not work. please see my updated code in the original post.

Comment: @ShehzadiAziz that's because you're printing the last value `num` had. You're not printing the max or min value of the list.

Comment: @ShehzadiAziz I added some working code to the answer, good luck with the course

Answer (score 0):

While not giving away the complete code due to the reasons your teacher stated, there are quite a few things to look at there:

The values aren't currently being returned since input always returns a string, and you need integers to compare, so *after* you input, you should add a line that tries to convert the input to an integer variable, something like this:

```
num = input('Enter a number:')
    if num != "done":
        try:
            num = int(num)
            number_list.append(num)
        except ValueError:
            print("Must be a number or the word 'done'")
```

Note that I also checked for a number_list variable that should be defined as an empty list beforehand. Lists are great for the purpose of storing many numbers on a single variable and then checking it for the largest and smallest number with the max() and min() arguments.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. however I am still having trouble using the list function in the loops of my code. Also, using the != was causing issues in my code and causing the loop to break after the user inputs one value. please see the edited post for my code now

Comment: The way you handled the != issue is fine. As for the current situation, keep in mind max and min are defaulted in Python so that if you just type ```print(max(number_list))``` it should return the largest number from your list without requiring the user of your functions. Same goes for minimum.